# Java: Arraylist of Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to make an arraylist of an array of 2 elements. So, I have unknown rows and known columns (i.e. 2). 
E.g. [{name1, ID1}, {name2, ID2}, ...]

I also have to return this arraylist.

I tried using

```
ArrayList<arr> alist = new ArrayList<arr>();
```

but don't know how to proceed.

Please advise.

Comment: wait return what arraylist

Comment: also is `arr` a variable or a class

Comment: please try providing us with more information next time, then we'd be able to provide you with better answers, and faster. also you would have a lesser chance of your question getting dislikes. :3

Comment: Also your question title is a bit misleading, it says "Array of Arraylist," but in your question you said "Arraylist of an Array."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a ArrayList must use a class. In this case, you can use a class Person:

```
class Person {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Then, we can define a ArrayList of Persons:

```
ArrayList<Person> array = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

```
array.get(0).getId();
array.get(0).getName();
```

Comment: Thanks Jhoel! 
Suppose it has a super class like Mammal and has a parameter: type.
If we want to fill the value for type, is super.type ="human" ok?

Comment: If you inherit from a superclass, you can pass the value by constructor using super (type) or we also inherit the setType () method from mammalian and assign it from there

Answer (score 0):

I have put here two simple ways to do it. However, you can think of many more such ways.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] arr;

        arr = new String[2];
        arr[0] = "name1";
        arr[1] = "ID1";
        list.add(arr);

        arr = new String[2];
        arr[0] = "name2";
        arr[1] = "ID2";
        list.add(arr);

        // Test
        for (String[] arrElem : list) {
            System.out.println(arrElem[0] + "\t" + arrElem[1]);
        }

        // Another option is to create a list of maps
        List<Map<String, String>> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, String> map = null;

        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("name1", "ID1");
        list2.add(map);

        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("name2", "ID2");
        list2.add(map);

        // Test
        for (Map<String, String> mapElem : list2) {
            System.out.println(mapElem);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
name1   ID1
name2   ID2
{name1=ID1}
{name2=ID2}
```

Comment: This will print "name2 ID2" twice because you are not creating a copy of the array

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash You are using raw types, these should be parameterized.